# Updating a Turtle.write Function as a Counter

Tags: python, methods, counter, turtle-graphics

So in this simulation I have bears, fish, and plants doing various things on a grid.  Once the simulation starts I have variables from the simulation function update the number of bears and fish in the world class constructor under fishCount and bearCount.  I have another method in the World class that turtle.writes the amount of bears and turtles as a counter.  Two problems. The initial count number for each creature is wrong on startup and when the counts are updated via breeding the showCounts method keeps writing over the previous count, making it hard to read.  I want it to update the counts on the screen each time a new bear/fish is made or when one dies.

Here is my code:

```
from math import *
from turtle import *
from random import *
import turtle
import random
import math

def mainSimulation():
    numberOfBears = 5
    numberOfFish = 5
    numberOfPlants = 5
    worldLifeTime = 2500
    worldWidth = 30
    worldHeight = 25

    myworld = World(worldWidth,worldHeight,numberOfBears,numberOfFish)
    myworld.draw()
    myworld.getBearStarvePass()
    myworld.getBearBreedPass()
    myworld.setBearStarvePass(25)
    myworld.setBreedPass(3)
    myworld.getFishOvercrowdNum()
    myworld.getFishBreedPass()
    myworld.setFishOvercrowdNum(5)
    myworld.setFishBreedPass(2)

    for i in range(numberOfFish):
        newfish = Fish(myworld)
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newfish,x,y)

    for i in range(numberOfBears):
        newbear = Bear(myworld)
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newbear,x,y)

    for i in range(numberOfPlants):
        newplant = Plant()
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newplant,x,y)

    for i in range(worldLifeTime):
        myworld.liveALittle()
        myworld.showCounts()


    myworld.freezeWorld()
```

THIS IS THE WORLD CLASS

```
class World:
    def __init__(self,mx,my,bear,fish):
        self.maxX = mx
        self.maxY = my
        self.thingList = []
        self.grid = []
        self.bearCount = bear
        self.fishCount = fish
        self.fishOvercrowdNum = 0
        self.fishBreedNum =0
        self.bearStarvePass = 0
        self.bearBreedPass = 0

        for arow in range(self.maxY):
            row=[]
            for acol in range (self.maxX):
                row.append(None)
            self.grid.append(row)

        self.wturtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.wscreen = turtle.Screen()
        self.wscreen.setworldcoordinates(0,0,self.maxX-1,self.maxY-1)
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Bear.gif")
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Fish.gif")
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Plant.gif")
        self.wturtle.hideturtle()

    def getBearStarvePass(self):
        return self.bearStarvePass

    def getBearBreedPass(self):
        return self.bearBreedPass

    def setBearStarvePass(self, newNum):
        self.bearStarvePass = newNum

    def setBreedPass(self, newNum):
        self.bearBreedPass = newNum

    def getFishOvercrowdNum(self):
        return self.fishOvercrowdNum

    def getFishBreedPass(self):
        return self.fishBreedNum

    def setFishOvercrowdNum(self, newNum):
        self.fishOvercrowdNum = newNum

    def setFishBreedPass(self, newNum):
        self.fishBreedNum = newNum

    def showCounts(self):
        bearCount = self.bearCount
        fishCount = self.fishCount
        self.wturtle.write("Bear: %d Fish: %d " % (bearCount, fishCount), move = False)

    def getNumBears(self):
        return self.bearCount

    def getNumFish(self):
        return self.fishCount

    def incBear(self):
        self.bearCount = self.bearCount + 1

    def incFish(self):
        self.fishCount = self.fishCount + 1

    def decBear(self):
        self.bearCount = self.bearCount - 1

    def decFish(self):
        self.fishCount = self.fishCount - 1



    def draw(self):
        self.wscreen.tracer(0)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        for i in range(self.maxY-1):
            self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
            self.wturtle.backward(self.maxX-1)
            self.wturtle.left(90)
            self.wturtle.forward(1)
            self.wturtle.right(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(1)
        self.wturtle.right(90)
        for i in range(self.maxX-2):
            self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
            self.wturtle.backward(self.maxY-1)
            self.wturtle.left(90)
            self.wturtle.forward(1)
            self.wturtle.right(90)
        self.wscreen.tracer(1)



    def freezeWorld(self):
        self.wscreen.exitonclick()

    def addThing(self,athing,x,y):
        a = 0
        athing.setX(x)
        athing.setY(y)
        self.grid[y][x] = athing
        athing.setWorld(self)
        self.thingList.append(athing)
        athing.appear()
        if isinstance(athing, Bear):
            self.bearCount = self.bearCount + 1
        elif isinstance(athing, Fish):
            self.fishCount = self.fishCount + 1

    def delThing (self, athing):
        athing.hide()
        self.grid[athing.getY()][athing.getX()] = None
        self.thingList.remove(athing)

    def moveThing(self,oldx,oldy,newx,newy):
        self.grid[newy][newx] = self.grid[oldy][oldx]
        self.grid[oldy][oldx] = None

    def getMaxX(self):
        return self.maxX

    def getMaxY(self):
        return self.maxY

    def liveALittle(self):
        if self.thingList != [ ]:
            athing = random.randrange(len(self.thingList))
            randomthing = self.thingList[athing]
            randomthing.liveALittle()

    def emptyLocation(self,x,y):
        if self.grid[y][x] == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def lookAtLocation(self,x,y):
        return self.grid[y][x]
```

This is the Bear Class

```
class Bear:
    def __init__(self, theWorld):
        self.turtle=turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Bear.gif")
        self.offsetList = [(-1,1) ,(0,1) ,(1,1),
                            (-1,0)        ,(1,0),
                            (-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1)]
        self.theWorld = theWorld
        self.bearStarvePass = self.theWorld.bearStarvePass
        self.bearBreedPass = self.theWorld.bearBreedPass

        self.xpos=0
        self.ypos=0
        self.world=None

        self.starveTick=0
        self.breedTick=0

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def move(self, newx, newy):
        self.world.moveThing(self.xpos, self.ypos, newx, newy)
        self.xpos = newx
        self.ypos = newy
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)


    def liveALittle(self):
        self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
        if self.breedTick >= self.bearBreedPass:
            self.tryToBreed()

        self.tryToEat()

        if self.starveTick == self.bearStarvePass:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.tryToMove()

    def tryToMove(self):
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
        randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx=self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty=self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and
                  0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY() ):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
            randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx=self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty=self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx,nexty):
            self.move(nextx,nexty)


    def tryToBreed(self):
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
        randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
            randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            childThing = Bear(self.theWorld)
            self.world.addThing(childThing, nextx, nexty)
            self.breedTick = 0



    def tryToEat(self):
        adjprey = []
        for offset in self.offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
                if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx,newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx,newy),Fish):
                    adjprey.append(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx,newy))

        if len(adjprey)>0:
            randomprey = adjprey[random.randrange(len(adjprey))]
            preyx = randomprey.getX()
            preyy = randomprey.getY()

            self.world.delThing(randomprey)
            self.move(preyx,preyy)
            self.starveTrick = 0

        else:
            self.starveTick = self.starveTick + 1
```

This is the CLass Fish

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, theworld):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Fish.gif")
        self.offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                            (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                            (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        self.theWorld = theworld
        self.overcrowd = self.theWorld.fishOvercrowdNum
        self.breed = self.theWorld.fishBreedNum

        self.xpos = 0
        self.ypos = 0
        self.world = None

        self.breedTick = 0

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos  = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def move(self, newx, newy):
        self.world.moveThing(self.xpos, self.ypos, newx, newy)
        self.xpos = newx
        self.ypos = newy
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)

    def liveALittle(self):
        adjfish = 0
        for offset in self.offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
                if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx, newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx, newy), Fish):
                    adjfish = adjfish + 1

        if adjfish >= self.overcrowd:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
            if self.breedTick >= self.breed:
                self.tryToBreed()

        self.tryToMove()

    def tryToBreed(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                      (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                      (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            childThing = Fish(self.theWorld)
            self.world.addThing(childThing, nextx, nexty)
            self.breedTick = 0

    def tryToMove(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                  (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                  (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            self.move(nextx, nexty)
```

This is the Class Plant

```
class Plant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Plant.gif")

        self.xpos = 0
        self.ypos = 0
        self.world = None

        self.breedTick = 0

#accessor and mutators

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def tryToBreed(self):
        offsetList=[(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),
                    (-1,0)      ,(1,0),
                    (-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1)]
        randomOffsetIndex=random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset=offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx=self.xpos+randomOffset[0]
        nexty=self.ypos+randomOffset[1]
        while not(0<=nextx<self.world.getMaxX()and
                  0<=nexty<self.world.getMaxY() ):
            randomOffsetIndex=random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset=offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx=self.xpos+randomOffset[0]
            nexty=self.ypos+randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx,nexty):
            childThing=Plant()
            self.world.addThing(childThing,nextx,nexty)
            self.breedTick=0

    def liveALittle(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                      (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                      (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
        if self.breedTick >= 5:
            self.tryToBreed()
        adjplant = 0
        for offset in offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
               if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx, newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx, newy), Plant):
                       adjplant = adjplant + 1

        if adjplant >= 2:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
            if self.breedTick >= 12:
                self.tryToBreed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainSimulation()
```

Comment: Is all of this source code necessary to understand and solve the issue?

Comment: I suppose not.  The most important part I suppose is the World Class and the mainSimulation function.  The rest is needed to see the full simulation.  I wasn't sure if I should have posted it.  I thought it would be good context.

Comment: You probably need to use `wturtle.clear` in `showCounts` to remove the old time before writing the new time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with @Tankobot's `wturtle.clear()` suggestion is that it wipes everything `wturtle` may have done.  So, you'll want a separate turtle just for drawing the text.  A related approach is not to clear, but to ***undo*** the last write command, if you're using a current Python 3 turtle module:

The scenario for the ***undo*** approach is:

Initial Setup:

1. Create a separate turtle, make it invisible (hideturtle) and pen up.
   (You don't need to have the pen down to do `turtle.write()`)
2. Move your turtle to where you want the counters to appear.
3. Write out an initial (zero'd) set of counters.

Runtime:

1. Before you call `turtle.write()`, call `turtle.undo()` to remove the previous counters.
2. Call `turtle.write()` to display the updated counters. You don't need to move the turtle into position first if it was located correctly for the previous write.

An example I wrote for a turtle user who wanted to know [How to output variable on turtle screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418203/how-to-output-variable-on-turtle-screen/40427563#40427563)